# Change time of expiration for reset password link in magento back-end

Tags: magento

Is it possible to change (reduce) the time after which the time of the reset password link expires ? Somewhere in the admin panel perhaps...

Answer (score 2):

In the Admin Panel :

Go to 
`System -> Configuration`
`Advanced -> Admin -> Security` 
and change `Password Lifetime (days)` and `Password Change` fields.

Comment: I don't have `Password Lifetime` and "Password Change`. I have only `Session lifetime` in the Admin/Security tab...

Comment: I found another one -> `Recovery Link Expiration Period (days)` but the minimum is 1 day... and I need something like 2 minutes.

Comment: OK, you might use another version of magento. Anyway, you can lookup in the code where is that field used, and then overload the corresponding method to allow it using values in seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But what I did is I went to the core code and in the function that returns true or false for the check whether the link has expired - I put it to always return true (so the link is always expired) and I accomplished my testing purpose. :)

Comment: @Syspect could u please let us know full path of core code and its function

Answer (score 2):

Using admin panel you only can increase recover link lifetime. Setting value in days.

You can find this setting here: 
**System** -> **Configuration** page
**Customers** section -> **Customer Configuration** -> **Password Options** -> **Recovery Link Expiration Period**

But you always can override *isResetPasswordLinkTokenExpired* method in **Mage_Customer_Model_Customer** model, which check expiration date.